# Generating a random string using RandomNumberGenerator - Is it random enough?

Tags: c#, random, cryptography

I'm generating random strings that ideally should be unique (I'm checking uniqueness as they are inserted into the DB), the strings are 12 characters long.
Here is my code

```
var alphabet = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
var uniqueCode = new char[12];
for (var i = 0; i < codeLength; i++)
{
   uniqueCode[i] = alphabet[RandomNumberGenerator.GetInt32(alphabet.Length)];
}
```

If I'm using RandomNumberGenerator which is cryptographic do i need to worry about adding any other uniqueness? Masking, etc
Looking at the C# port of nanoId i can see there is some masking but is this really needed if RandomNumberGenerator is truly random ?

NanoId Masking Example

```
        internal static int Clz32(int x)
        {
            const int numIntBits = sizeof(int) * 8; //compile time constant
            //do the smearing
            x |= x >> 1;
            x |= x >> 2;
            x |= x >> 4;
            x |= x >> 8;
            x |= x >> 16;
            //count the ones
            x -= x >> 1 & 0x55555555;
            x = (x >> 2 & 0x33333333) + (x & 0x33333333);
            x = (x >> 4) + x & 0x0f0f0f0f;
            x += x >> 8;
            x += x >> 16;
            return numIntBits - (x & 0x0000003f); //subtract # of 1s from 32
        }
```

https://github.com/codeyu/nanoid-net/blob/master/src/Nanoid/Nanoid.cs

Comment: The only thing that is really random is nature.  Mathematical random number generators are not perfectly random but close enough for most cases. Depending on the crypto algorithm some seeds may be less secure than others.

Comment: your identifier has `log2(36)*12` (i.e. ~62) bits of entropy, hence (via the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)) you should expect a 50% chance of seeing a duplicate when you've generated `2**31` of these identifiers.  as your DB is ensuring uniqueness you should make sure it retries appropriately on duplicates

Comment: @jdweng CSPRNGs do a much better job of producing IID uniform variates (i.e. what's wanted here) than anything in nature!  the (only?) advantage of "true" RNGs is that there isn't any state to be compromised.  also your comment about "some seeds may be less secure than others" doesn't seem to apply as it will be using entropy from the OS

Comment: @SamMason : I was referring to the crypto key not the Random Number being less secure.  Suppose you seeded a crypto key with all zeroes or all ones?

Comment: @jdweng I don't see OP referring to any "crypto key" anywhere. I agree that a lack of entropy is bad, but it's LSFRs that deal with this particularly badly and they aren't CSPRNGs (so not sure how this applies)

Comment: in many of the programming languages I have seen, every random method or function will take a seed argument. In order to achieve "true" randomness, System time is fed in as the seed. The rationale is: time is always moving forward meaning the value of the current system time is guaranteed to be a unique seed. I believe that C# takes this approach when using the random methods without passing in a seed argument.

Comment: @Narish OP suggested they are using [`RandomNumberGenerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator?view=net-7.0) which uses the OS for entropy, i.e. there is no way of seeding it (AFAIK).  any reasonable RNG will also use the OS as an entropy source when not given a seed, the current time is a terrible choice as it's very predictable (as it's supposed to be!)

Comment: @SamMason thanks for the clarification, I dug around for the dotnet source code and although I don't understand what they are doing, you seem to be right that system time isn't involved. I do see some [masking](https://source.dot.net/#System.Security.Cryptography/System/Security/Cryptography/RandomNumberGenerator.cs,ec2801e320ce31ea) taking place

Comment: @Narish you want to look in `RandomNumberGeneratorImplementation.FillSpan` for where it actually does the generation. the code you pointed to is just transforming it to an unbiased range, https://www.pcg-random.org/posts/bounded-rands.html has some explanations of other variants